# How to notify user of new message?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I need to update the user's messages when a new one was sent to him.
I know that I can create a SQL Trigger and get it using CLR Triggers.
But how do I notify the user without having some method polling to see if something's changed?
How do I know that I have new messages without check the database every time?

It's 100% similar to an email system or the facebook message system.
One user will send a message to another, how to get that new message without having a method checking the database for changes from time to time?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and ASP.NET MVC3.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of messages are you talking about? For events happening in the database, for database users?

Comment: A Message is inserted in the database. I create a trigger to get that event and get it on C# using CLR Triggers. Now the question is how to notify the user that event happened? Was I clear?

Comment: And what's wrong with pooling the database every x seconds?

Comment: No, not at all clear. You want a person to walk up to their desk and tell them they have a message? You want a phone call to be made from the db server's modem? You want an SMS sent? EMail? Smoke signals? Carrier pigeon? Telegram?

Comment: @WiktorZychla performance? If I can use a trigger, why would I use "check-recheck"? Apparantely I'm wrong...

Comment: @AndrewBarber Think of an email app. When you write a email to someone, that someone needs to be notified of that new message. That's what I need. I updated my question with this explanation.

Comment: You haven't given us any real context at all. So, you want them to get an email telling them they have an email???

Comment: @AndrewBarber Well, actually facebook and GMail are the contexts. I'm a facebook user and I send a message to another facebook user. The system inserts my message in the database and then notifies the recipient he's got a new message. That's about what I need.

Comment: You need us to tell you how to access a database?

Comment: @AndrewBarber No, I know how to access the DB and how to get the inserted message using CLR Triggers. What I need to know is how to notify the user he's got a new message since MVC is done by request.

Comment: Finally, you're *starting* to get somewhere. We can't read your mind... If it's "100% like email" as you claim, you are doing it all wrong, unless you expect someone to have your website open 24/7. You don't trigger from the database... you check for messages from the application.

Comment: When you talked about database triggers, you made it seem like you were sending administrative alerts. A database trigger is *not* the place to trigger application functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the SignalR (https://github.com/SignalR). You'd have to perform tests on how it behaves in your environment.

Comment: agreed. if all you are trying to do is send a message to the client from the server then signalR is definitely what you are looking for.  

have a look at hanselmans post (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) or this awesome blog post on creating a chat app in mvc 3 (http://sergiotapia.com/2011/09/signalr-with-mvc3-chat-app-build-asynchronous-real-time-persistant-connection-websites/)